# What's the equivalent of 'getElementsByTagName' in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the equivalent of `getElementsByTagName()` in jQuery? I just want to create a collection of elements in jQuery so I can iterate through them and do something with each item.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
$("tagnamehere")
```

So:

```
$("div").each(function() {
    // do something exciting with each div
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");

    // do something by directly manipulating the wrapped DOM element
    this.style.border = "1px solid red";

    // do something only if this particular div has a class of 'pretty'
    if($(this).hasClass("pretty")) {
        $(this).text("I am the pretty one");
    }
});
```

or just:

```
// apply some css to all div elements
$("div").css("border", "1px solid red");
```

Keep in mind that when you use jQuery to select a number of elements, e.g. `$("span")`, any method you invoke on the object will happen on *all matched elements*. Think of it as 'implicit iteration' - e.g. `$("span").hide();` will hide all span elements on the page.

See:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/
- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
- http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Worth noting I think that this is dealing with jQuery objects though - not DOM elements.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder & karim79: Interesting. So what about doing something on a specific item in the collection?

Comment: It depends on what you mean. If you want to target a specific element in the DOM, you need to 'select' it. For example, `$("#myDiv")` will get you the div with id attribute set to myDiv.

Comment: @Shaoz: *"So what about doing something on a specific item in the collection?"* You can loop through them with `each`, as Karim has shown, or you can address them directly via `[]` notation: `$('div')[0].xxx;` More here: http://api.jquery.com/get/ (You can use `[]` or `get()`, either one; `get()` has a couple of extra features, but mostly you want `[]` if you don't need those features.) It's well worth reading through the jQuery API (http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end, you'll get a much better understanding of it and it only takes an hour or so.

Comment: what I mean is that my elements are dynamically generated, so I would need to target a specific item in the collection to do something. i.e. the 3 item should do something when it appears...

Comment: @Shaoz - You can target the third div like this: `$("div:eq(2)")`. That's called the `:eq` selector. I suggest you go through the links I posted in my answer (in particular, the second one) to get a feel for how jQuery and CSS selectors work.

Answer (score 7):

Just use the element selector

```
$('elementname')
```

E.g.

```
$('div')
```

And to do the iteration:

```
$('div').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    //insert code here
});
```

You may not have to iterate, however, as a method called upon the collection will be called for each item in the collection, so

```
$('div').hide();
```

...will hide all divs.

Comment: `$("[foo]")` is the Has Attribute Selector, not the Element Selector.

Comment: I'm sure it's a typo since the examples use the proper code but it's very misleading.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Yes, I was using the [] to indicate a placeholder, but I realise that was misleading! Have modified accoringly.

Answer (score 4):

Given a string `tagName`, this statement:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)
```

...could be written using jQuery:

```js
$(tagName)
```

Given a native DOM element `element` and a string `tagName`, this statement:

```js
element.getElementsByTagName(tagName)
```

...could be written using jQuery:

```js
$(element).find(tagName)
```

**Note :** Using `getElementsByTagName` you get native DOM elements, meanwhile using jQuery statements you get jQuery objects. If you want native DOM elements with jQuery you could use `get()` - [How do I pull a native DOM element from a jQuery object?](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/)

Answer (score -4):

Just need put something like:

```
var some = $('[name="tagname"]');
```

Comment: No, that's incorrect. Your code is an example of an attribute selector. See https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/