# undefined variable within nested loops

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined, nested-loops

I have this series of nested loops that controls the layout of a series of tabs within a document.

```
var k=0;
while(k<document.getElementsByTagName("h7").length){
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[k].style.left=i*154+"px";
    document.getElementsByTagName("h7")[k].style.left=i*154+"px";
    if(i==0){
        document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[k].style.left="42px";
        document.getElementsByTagName("h7")[k].style.left="42px";
    }
    k++;
  }
}
```

It works in the browser console with an error saying that `document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[k].style.left=i*154+"px";` is undefined.  I assume that there's something wrong with my `k` variable scope.  Can anyone help me?  I've tried all kinds of things, including passing the parameter `k` instead of using a variable but nothing seems to resolve the issue.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zbpzu/

Here's the sample HTML

```
<h2>Header 2-1</h2>
<h7>header 7-1</h7>

<h2>Header 2-2</h2>
<h7>header 7-2</h7>

<h2>Header 2-3</h2>
<h7>header 7-3</h7>

<h2>Header 2-4</h2>
<h7>header 7-4</h7>

<h2>Header 2-5</h2>
<h7>header 7-5</h7>

<h2>Header 2-6</h2>
<h7>header 7-6</h7>

<h2>Header 2-7</h2>
<h7>header 7-7</h7>

<h2>Header 2-8</h2>
<h7>header 7-8</h7>

<h2>Header 2-9</h2>
<h7>header 7-9</h7>

<h2>Header 2-10</h2>
<h7>header 7-10</h7>

<h2>Header 2-11</h2>
<h7>header 7-11</h7>

<h2>Header 2-12</h2>
<h7>header 7-12</h7>

<h2>Header 2-13</h2>
<h7>header 7-13</h7>
```

Thank you!

Comment: do u have a link. or can u create a jsfiddle

Comment: is no of `h2` elements are equal to no of `h7` elements? If you can post html, would be helpful. I think you have more `h7` than 'h2'.

Comment: Yes, no of h2 and h7 are equal.  I'll work on a fiddle...

Comment: Pretty sure you need {var i} in the inner for loop. Unless it is declared somewhere above what you have posted.

Comment: Your `k++` is in the wrong spot.

Comment: There's a fiddle added.  It works in the fiddle fine too...I'm not sure what the issue is. Maybe just firefox doesn't like it?

Comment: @user2434247: And you've made sure that you have the same number of `<h2>` and `<h7>` elements in the jsFiddle as you do in your code, right?

Comment: good call...let me fix that

Comment: It looks rather messy in the fiddle but yes, it works as expected.  On the website, these headers are supposed to be overlapped.  The first five only show...when you click next, those disappear and the next 5 show.

Comment: So if you intend for the `k++` to be right there, then why do you have the outer loop? If the inner loop size (5) doesn't match the quantity of `<h7>` elements, you're going to get the error.

Comment: I want every group of 5 h2 and h7 to lay on top of the previous group of 5

Comment: And the quantity of h2/h7 elements is an exact multiple of 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Crazy Train for pointing out the problem....Here's the fix!

```
for(k=0;k<document.getElementsByTagName("h7").length;){
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  if(k<document.getElementsByTagName("h7").length){
    document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[k].style.left=i*154+"px";
    document.getElementsByTagName("h7")[k].style.left=i*154+"px";
    if(i===0){
        document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[k].style.left="42px";
        document.getElementsByTagName("h7")[k].style.left="42px";
    }
    k++;
   }
}
}
```

I needed the extra if statement to ensure that the inner loop didn't go longer than the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a for loop for `k` too like `i`

```
var h7length=document.getElementsByTagName("h7").length;
for(k=0;k<h7length;k++){
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    if(i==0){
        document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[k].style.left="42px";
        document.getElementsByTagName("h7")[k].style.left="42px";
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[k].style.left=i*154+"px";
    document.getElementsByTagName("h7")[k].style.left=i*154+"px";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @MoazzamKhan: Ojal's answer is not the same as the code in the question. It does (should) solve the problem.

Comment: This does not solve the problem.  I tried this originally but the outer loop ends before the inner one is finished, this way.

Comment: I still get the same undefined error with the jquery script you provided.  But I might tinker with it a bit more....

Comment: use combination of jQuery and javascript:

Apply some class to header elements and give some IDs, then they can be accessed in below code:

$("h7").each(function() {
});


[Stack Overflow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398553/whats-the-equivalent-of-getelementsbytagname-in-jquery)

Comment: @user2434247 please paste your sample HTML too. so we can identify the undefined element.

Comment: @Ojal Suthar my HTML is added!